# What is a "free-entry?" What is the number of free entries of a 3-by-3 skew symmetric matrice?

Tags: linear-algebra

First of all, I presume that a free-entry is a non-zero term in the matrix and for the 3-by-3 skew symmetric matrix, I determined that the number of free-entries was 6. But I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: No, free entry means, which is not determined by the others. In case of size $3$, only $3$ are free. So the vector space of real skew-symmetric matrices of size $3$ is $3$. In general, it is $n(n-1)/2$ for $n$ odd.

Answer (score 0):

Here "the number of free entries" means the number of coefficients that can bee *freely* chosen, without constraints. So for a 3-by-3 skew-symmetric matrix, you have correctly determined that at least 3 coefficients must be $0$ (and are therefore not free to choose), but that is not the only constraint.

Suppose you have (freely) chosen the coefficient at the $(1,2)$ position. Can you then freely choose the coefficient at the position $(2,1)$?